# Remove MKPointAnnotation 3D effect (make flat colour)

Tags: swift, uikit, mapkit, mkannotation

I am trying to remove the 3D effect on an MKPointAnnotation.

**This is my marker with the 3D effect (or shadow)**

[image: Marker with gradient]

**This is a flat colour marker (picture from the internet)**

[image: Marker without gradient]

I assume that you can change this somewhere in this function, which I have been able to successfully change the color of the marker

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MyMarker")
    annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor.blue
    return annotationView
}
```

[image: Marker with colour]

Does anyone know how to make the colour flat and remove the 3D effect?

Comment: The 3D effect is new with iOS 16, the flat is before iOS 16. I'm not aware of an easy way to remove that.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to any changelog about this? Seems so weird as it’s like a step back in design

Comment: Run it in an iOS 15 emulator and you should have the flat design if I'm right